# Установка kivy и django в python

Tags: python, django, kivy, установка

на какую версию python3 можно скачать последнюю версию kivy и django

Answer (score 0):

в доках kivy написано:
Python 2.7 and 3.5 to 3.7 is supported.

в доках django написано:
Get the latest version of Python at https://www.python.org/downloads/ or with your operating system’s package manager.